# How to install CMD in wine.

Tags: command-line, wine

How to install CMD in wine3.0? Because its CMD is not working. I tried to install freedom fighter but it will not install without CMD.

Answer (score 7):

Command prompt already exists in wine 3.0. You can run it by typing `wine cmd` in terminal.

Comment: No this is not working.

Comment: Can you post the output of the above command ? What's the error ?

Comment: @ghanshyamswami: Could you please edit your question to explain what *exactly* you tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: doesn't work as we can know from https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2125628#p2125628